# When was S.browser_fallback_url introduced in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent, progressive-web-apps

I'm writing a web application (JavaScript, angularJS, etc) that runs better on Chrome, so it tries to launch it when, it's running on Android and it's opened on the default Android Browser. 
If Chrome isn't installed, I want it to go back to the Android Browser (instead of the Google Play store).

So I'm using an intent of this form:
intent://localhost:3011/#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;S.browser_fallback_url=http://localhost:3011/?intent=no;end

My problem is that when I run this on my android tablet (no-name, Lollipop 5.1.1, Default browser: Chrome 39) it doesn't work. When I use the separately installed Chrome (trying to load, e.g. firefox which isn't installed) it works.

So in order to proceed I need to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's some other reason.
My question really boils down to this: should the browser_fallback_url work in the old default browser, or is it a newer feature in Chrome (so it's useless to my use-case).

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I worked on this and [wrote about it](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/) and [updated the official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) it was introduced in Chrome 40.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Kinlan How canI  open PlayStore link with Referral parameters in Chrome?